# iterar un objeto serializado

Tags: c#, datagrid, foreach

tengo el siguiente nameSpace con 2 clases....

```
namespace SchemaSpec
{
[Serializable]
public class ItemSpecification
{
    public enum JetDataType
    {
        Bit,
        Byte,
        Short,
        Long,
        Currency,
        Single,
        Double,
        DateTime,
        Text,
        Memo
    };

    public int ColumnNumber { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public JetDataType TypeData { get; set; }

    public int ColumnWidth { get; set; }
}



[Serializable]
public class SchemeDef
{

    public SchemeDef()
    {
        DelimiterType = DelimType.CsvDelimited;
        ColumnDefinition = new List<ItemSpecification>();
        UsesHeader = FirstRowHeader.No;
    }


    public enum DelimType
    {
        CsvDelimited,
        TabDelimited,
        CustomDelimited,
        FixedWidth
    };


    public enum FirstRowHeader
    {
        Yes,
        No
    };


    public DelimType DelimiterType { get; set; }
    public string CustomDelimiter { get; set; }
    public List<ItemSpecification> ColumnDefinition { get; set; }
    public FirstRowHeader UsesHeader { get; set; }
   }
}
```

en un método donde llamo esta clase en un foreach...

```
         SchemaSpec.SchemeDef sdef = new SchemaSpec.SchemeDef();
  int i = 0;
                foreach (SchemaSpec.ItemSpecification s in sdef.ColumnDefinition)
                {
                    dgvMaster.Columns[i].HeaderText = s.Name;
                    i++;
                }
```

me sale error (en verde, Advertencia?) en la linea **dgvMaster.Columns[i].HeaderText = s.Name** El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección. intento cambiar el foreach con un for pero no he podido como interar con el SchemaSpec.ItemSpecification

Comment: dgvMaster.Columns[i] estas aumentando el valor de las columnas por cada iteracion, suponiendo que quieres el titulo en encabezado columna 3 tu sentencia es dgvMaster.Columns[2].HeaderText = s.Name

Comment: @MiguelZarate segun tu respuesta es mejor eliminar el i++? este código lo tome de github y es lo mas parecido a lo que necesito realizar... si quito el i++ me toma la segunda columna.. creo que seria manejar esto con un for!!!

Comment: ya entendi estas haciendo un recorrido a los encabezados,solo agregale un limite a i ejemplo:  if  i>4 break para 5 columnas

Comment: Como estas creando las columnas del dgvMaster? porque quizas la cantidad de items de ColumnDefinition, no sea la misma que la columnas que tengas en el grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sino es confiable localizar la columna por su posicion podrias buscarla ayudandote con `linq`

Algo como esto

```
foreach (SchemaSpec.ItemSpecification s in sdef.ColumnDefinition)
{
    var col = dgvMaster.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Name == s.Name);

    if(col != null)
    {
        col.HeaderText = s.Name;
    }

}
```

Entiendo que `Name` es el nombre de la columna, pero quizas debas definir otra propiedad que indique el nombre que tendra el header

Comment: @LeandorTuttini Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'Cast' toma 1 argumentos Error al colocar esta parte de código, No entiendo para que usas c=> c.Name == s.Name?? ...  el name es el atributo de la clase ItemSpecification lo unico que se pretende es llevar este a tributo a columnheader de el datagrid

Comment: disculpa, olvide una paete del linq, ahi edite el codigo

Comment: Recuerda que las columnas del grid deben tener la propiedad Name coincidente con la que tienes en el objeto que iteras en el foreach, lo planteo porque no especificas como estas creando las columnas, imagine usas el Columns.Add()